# getwindowtext not retrieving text

Tags: delphi, api, delphi-7

I tried the following code but it does not retrieve text from foreground window!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  title : pansichar;
  s : string;
begin
    GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), title,GetWindowTextLength(GetForegroundWindow()) + 1);
    s := title;
    showmessage(s);
end;
```

Comment: Your code says "Form1" to me. And this **is** the title (= text) of the current active window.

Comment: Shouldn't that "title" pointer actually be pointing to something on the way in?

Comment: its giving me access voilation error and if i initialize the title it just gives initialized value

Comment: ALWAYS specify version of delphi - it's often crucial

Comment: Suggestion: If some of your questions have been answered, you should flag the answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this one:

```
var
  hwndForeground: HWND;
  titleLength: Integer;
  title: string;
begin
  hwndForeground := GetForegroundWindow();
  titleLength := GetWindowTextLength(hwndForeground);
  SetLength(title, titleLength);
  GetWindowText(hwndForeground, PChar(title), titleLength + 1);
  title := PChar(title);

  ShowMessage(title);
end;
```

Comment: I've edited this to make it work for Unicode versions of Delphi as well.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line:

```
  title : pansichar;
```

with this:

```
  title: array[0..255] of Char;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  title : array[0..254] of Char;
  s : string;
begin
    GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), title,255);
    s := title;
    showmessage(s);
end;
```

Bye.

Comment: now i am getting this error:[Error] Unit1.pas(31): Incompatible types: 'Array' and 'PAnsiChar'

Comment: btw i am using delphi 7 maybe widechars are not supported

Comment: yes removing ''wide'' made it work but why didnt widechar work?

Comment: If you're going to tell the function that there are `GetWindowTextLength + 1` characters in the array, then you should **use dynamic allocation** to ensure that there really are that many characters in the array, instead of using an array with 255 elements, which is completely arbitrary.

Comment: Rob Thanks for the advice, I revised the code. to avoid problems with GetWindowTextLength . ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  liHwnd, liLength : Integer;
  lpChar : PChar;
begin
  liHwnd := GetForegroundWindow();
  liLength := GetWindowTextLength(liHwnd) + 1;
  lpChar := StrAlloc(liLength);
  Try
    GetWindowText(liHwnd, lpChar, liLength);

    showmessage(lpChar);
  Finally
    StrDispose(lpChar);
  End;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be, that you have [this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx)?